# In NodeJS, how can I get a password from input without the user's keypresses being echoed to the console?

Tags: node.js, prompt

I'm trying to add a simple setup prompt to my program, where it prompts for some basic details before starting the app for the first time. One of these inputs I need is a password. When I read this password, I want to ensure that (much like when you enter a password for `sudo`) it doesn't appear in the user's terminal as they type.

How can I do so within NodeJS? I'm looking for something I can drop into the following code.

```js
console.log('Failed to find config file');
// This echoes to the console - how can I do the same thing without the echo?
const password = prompt('Enter a password: ');
```

I'm happy to install a dependency from NPM if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`prompt-sync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) library to prompt for passwords.

```js
import createPrompt from 'prompt-sync';
const prompt = createPrompt({});

// The prompt object's hide method gives a prompt where the input 
// is hidden
const password = prompt.hide('Enter a password: ');
```